# UPDATE/DELETE performance on partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Hi I'm using table partitioning in my Postgres 9.3.

I've notice that the DELETE and UPDATE queries are much slower when I'm doing them via the parent table.

I see that the constraint_exclusion is working but it's around 10 times slower than deleting/updating directly the table.

Any reason why? Is the partition lookup so expensive??

I have over 300 partitions. Tables are partitioned by client_id.

directly

```
 (user@localhost:5432) [db01]  [*] # explain analyze delete from events_128 where datastream = 'API';
  Delete on events_128  (cost=0.42..4667.35 rows=13749 width=6) (actual time=55.394..55.394 rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Index Scan using events_128_datastream on events_128  (cost=0.42..4667.35 rows=13749 width=6) (actual time=0.086..5.396 rows=13821 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((datastream)::text = 'API'::text)
  Total runtime: 55.432 ms
 (4 rows)

 Time: 55.858 ms



 (user@localhost:5432) [db01]  [*] # delete from events_128 where datastream = 'API';
 DELETE 13821
 Time: 28.673 ms
```

via parent table

```
 (user@localhost:5432) [db01]  [*] # explain analyze delete from events where client_id = 128 and datastream = 'API';
  Delete on events  (cost=0.00..4701.72 rows=13750 width=6) (actual time=12.577..12.577 rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
          Filter: ((client_id = 128) AND ((datastream)::text = 'API'::text))
    ->  Index Scan using events_128_datastream on events_128  (cost=0.42..4701.72 rows=13749 width=6) (actual time=0.132..6.275 rows=13821 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((datastream)::text = 'API'::text)
          Filter: (client_id = 128)
  Total runtime: 12.645 ms
 (7 rows)

 Time: 315.475 ms


 (user@localhost:5432) [db01]  [*] # delete from events where client_id = 128 and datastream = 'API';
 DELETE 13821
 Time: 264.968 ms
```

Table definitions:

```
                     Table "public.events"
(user@localhost:5432) [db01]  [] > \d events

        Column             |           Type           | Modifiers 
-------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id                            | bigint                   | not null
 actions                       | bigint                   | 
 app_installs                  | bigint                   | 
 dimensions                    | hstore                   | 
 ... 20 more varchar or bigint or date
 datastream                    | character varying(255)   | 
 datastream_type               | character varying(40)    | 
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_client_id" FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(id)
Triggers:
    insert_events_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE events_insert_trigger()
Number of child tables: 254 (Use \d+ to list them.)


(user@localhost:5432) [db01]  [] > \d events_128
                       Table "public.events_128"
        Column             |           Type           | Modifiers 
-------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id                            | bigint                   | not null
 actions                       | bigint                   | 
 app_installs                  | bigint                   | 
 dimensions                    | hstore                   | 
 ... 20 more varchar or bigint or date
 datastream                    | character varying(255)   | 
 datastream_type               | character varying(40)    | 
Indexes:
    "events_128_unq_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)
    "events_128_channel" btree (channel)
    "events_128_client_id" btree (client_id)
    "events_128_datasource" btree (datasource)
    "events_128_datasource_class" btree (datasource_class)
    "events_128_datastream" btree (datastream)
    "events_128_datastream_type" btree (datastream_type)
    "events_128_rangeend" btree (rangeend)
    "events_128_rangestart" btree (rangestart)
Check constraints:
    "events_128_client_id_check" CHECK (client_id = 128)
Inherits: events
```

Comment: Inspect the output of `\d events`.  Do you see a trigger that fires on `DELETE`?

Comment: @dezso no DELETE trigger, just INSERT trigger that redirects the data into correct partition

Comment: It would seem prudent to provide relevant table definitions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter table defs provided

Comment: You are doing some dirty magic.  The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output shows 0 rows affected.  Afterwards, you are able to delete a number of rows.  Twice.  (Note that the plans show that the `DELETE` via the parent table is even faster.)  Could you clarify what you are actually doing?

Comment: @dezso all the statements were executed in a begin; ... rollback; block. I wanted to exclude the possibility of cold cache and to delete exactly the same data.

Comment: @dezso not sure what you mean, where do you see the 0? When you run EXPLAIN ANALYZE with DELETE statement it doesn't produce the 'DELETE XXXXX' output. As I said each statement was run in transaction and rolled back at the end. I've skipped those in the listing.

Comment: Well, it seems that an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE ...` does not report the number of rows in the row count.  (Nevertheless, it gets executed.)  It was a misunderstanding on my side.